# Styling php output

Tags: php, html, css

I want to style the membership status line at the top of each page. All the variables I want to include are in the following code which is working but I want to right justify the whole line, define font properties and add space between items displayed:

```
<?php 
if (!Am_Lite::getInstance()->isLoggedIn()) {
   echo Am_Lite::getInstance()->renderLoginForm();
   echo '<a href="'.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getSignupURL().'">Sign up</a>';
} else {
   echo 'Welcome '.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getUsername().'!
   <a href="'.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getLogoutURL().'">Log out </a>';
   echo '<a href="'.str_replace('/profile', '/member', Am_Lite::getInstance()->getProfileURL()).'">Account page</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: add classes to your tags and use css?

Comment: This should be tagged `css`, `html` because it has nothing to do with php.

Comment: Wrap your content inside a container (div for example) and style it with CSS. Nothing to deal with PHP, it's an HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: Sorry but it is to do with php. I have no problem styling html but don't seem to be able to do the same with individual element within <?php '> using <div> or <span>. Or incorporating a table so each output value goes into a separate cell, for example, in order to position them in the exact way I would like to.

Answer (score 1):

You style your php output the same way you do for HTML. Put the output in some tags (div for example), and add a style argument to your tag. For your case, something like this will work:

```
<div style='width:100%;text-align:right;padding:5px;font:15px arial,sans-serif;'>
<?php 
if (!Am_Lite::getInstance()->isLoggedIn()) {
   echo Am_Lite::getInstance()->renderLoginForm();
   echo '<a href="'.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getSignupURL().'">Sign up</a>';
} else {
   echo 'Welcome '.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getUsername().'!
   <a href="'.Am_Lite::getInstance()->getLogoutURL().'">Log out </a>';
   echo '<a href="'.str_replace('/profile', '/member', Am_Lite::getInstance()->getProfileURL()).'">Account page</a>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I can style the font for the whole line for instance, but I don't seem to be able to single out and style individual output separately or adjust the space in between them.

Comment: `echo "<span style='font:10px arial,sans-serif;'>".Am_Lite::getInstance()->getSignupURL()."</span>";`

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.align-right {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
</style>


<div class="align-right">content</div>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMMh8/